# Show a Particular Set of Sentences can be Represented with a WFF

Tags: number-theory, logic

## Problem

Let $A^{*}_{S}$ be the set of sentences consisting of S1, S2, and all sentences of the form

$\phi (0)\rightarrow\forall v_{1}(\phi (v_{1}\rightarrow\phi(Sv_{1}))\rightarrow\forall v_{1}\phi (v_{1})$

where $\phi$ is a formula ( in the language of $\mathfrak{N}_{S}$ in which no variable except $v_{1}$ occurs free. Show that $A_{S}\subseteq\mathrm{Cn}A^{*}_{S}$. Conclude that $\mathrm{Cn}A^{*}_{S}=\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}_{S}$. (Here $\phi(t)$ is by definition $\phi^{v_{1}}_{t}$. The sentence displayed above is called the induction axiom for $\phi$.)

Where

S1. $\forall x Sx\neq0$

S2. $\forall x \forall y (Sx=Sy\rightarrow x=y)$

S3. $\forall y(y\neq 0 \rightarrow \exists x y=Sx)$

S4.n $\forall x S^nx\neq x$

### So Far

So, I understand thus far that to show $A_{S}\subseteq\mathrm{Cn}A^{*}_{S}$ I need to show that the induction axiom above defines S3 and S4.n; I understand that the best way to do this is by induction, and that the base case for showing S3 is (below).  What I do not understand is where to take the induction step from there.

### Prove S3

Base Case: Let y in $\forall y(y\neq 0 \rightarrow \exists x y=Sx)$ be 0.  It is the case that $A_{S}^{*}\vdash(0\neq0\rightarrow\exists x0=Sx)$, as the antecedent is logically false ($\vdash 0\ne 0$).

Induction Step: ...Not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for **$S_3$** you are on the right track.

Your *induction formula* $\varphi(v_1)$ is :

> $(v_1≠0→∃x v_1 = Sx)$,

with *only* $v_1$ free.

You have already proved the *basis* case : $\varphi(0)$, i.e. $0≠0→∃x 0 = Sx$.

Now, you have to prove the *induction step*, i.e.that :

> $∀v_1(\varphi(v_1) → \varphi(Sv_1))$.

We have $S(v_1)=S(v_1)$; thus, by $\exists$-introduction :

$\exists x S(v_1)= S(x)$.

Apply now the *tautology* : $\mathcal A \rightarrow (\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal A)$ to get (by *modus ponens*) :

> $Sv_1 \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists x S(v_1)= S(x)$.

Now, by $\forall$-introduction :

> > $\forall v_1(Sv_1 \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists x S(v_1)= S(x))$.

Finally, having proved $\varphi(0)$ and $∀v_1(\varphi(v_1) → \varphi(Sv_1))$, we may apply the *Induction axiom* to get :

> $\forall v_1 (v_1≠0→∃x v_1 = Sx)$.

*Added*

Now for $S_{4.n}$, we need a sort of "double induction", on $n$ and on $x$.

Let start with $S_{4.1}$, i.e. $∀xSx≠x$; we will prove it by induction on $x$.

The *induction formula* is : $\varphi (x) := Sx \ne x$

For $n=0$, we have, by $S_1$ (we instantiate the universal quantifier with $x := 0$), that $S(0) \ne 0$, i.e. $\varphi (0)$.

Assume now as *Induction hypotheses* that $\varphi (n)$ holds, i.e.that $Sn \ne n$ : we have to show that it holds for $S(n)$. Assume for contradiction that $S(Sn)=Sn$; by $S_2$ we have that : $Sn=n$, contrary to *Induction hypotheses*; thus $S(Sn) \ne Sn$.

Again, having showed that $\varphi(0)$ and that $\forall x (\varphi(x) \rightarrow \varphi (Sx))$, we conclude that :

> > $\forall x \varphi(x)$, i.e.

$\forall x Sx \ne x$.

Thus, we have proved $S_{4.1}$; this is the *basis* for the "outer" induction on the "counter" $k$ of $S_{4.k}$.

We have now to prove that if $S_{4.k}$ holds, then also $S_{4.k+1}$ holds.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain how one 'applies' the Induction Axiom.

Comment: Is a sort of *modus ponens* : you have to prove $\varphi(0)$ and $\forall x (\varphi(x) \rightarrow \varphi(Sx))$. Having done these two proofs (the *basis* and the *induction step*) you use them to "detach" twice from the *Induction axiom* the *conclusion*, i.e $\forall x \varphi(x)$. To be convinced, write all the *Ind ax* with the complete formula $\varphi$ of your problem (using enough parentheses ...) and do all the proof step-by-step.

Comment: Alright I've about got it down now - now, unfortunately, I'm confused as to how one would define the induction step for proving sentence 4; assuming the base case is $(S^n0\neq 0)$, which is true by definition of Subsequent.

Comment: @Elidrake - I've expanded my answer.

Comment: That is considerably more clear, and exactly what I needed to finish this up - thank you good sir!